# How can I put this make this box go below the text like in the image

Tags: javascript, html, css

[image: []

I am trying to make this above layout. But unfortunately, I am not being able to put it as the above layout.
I am getting the 2nd image as my result. 
[image]

Codes:

```css
.text_box_holder{
  position: relative;

}
.text_box_holder h1{
  text-align: right;
  padding-right: 50%;
  color: #fff;
  background: inherit;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
}
.learn_more_in_box{

  color: #fde428;
  text-align: right;
  padding-left: 31% !important;

  -webkit-background-clip: text;

}
.yellow_box{
  position: absolute;
  border: 7px solid #fde428;
  width: 40%;
  height: 300px;

}
```

```html
  <div class="text_box_holder">
    <div class="yellow_box"></div>
    <h1>Consumer<br>Products<br>Consulting</h1>
    <a href="" class="learn_more_in_box">LEARN MORE</a>
  </div>
```

Comment: Please do clear that what do you want to do..

Comment: Are you trying to create a fieldset?

Comment: Your samples are probaly divs with a background image, as it is much easier and cross-browser friendly.

Comment: these are not really background images. But I am trying to make it with HTML and CSS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try following code . I didn't add any back ground images . I have tried only to add 2 text with the box .

**HTML**

```
<div class="text_box_holder">
    <div class="yellow_box"> </div>
    <div class="text1"> 
      <h1>Consumer<br>Products<br>Consulting</h1>
      <div class="text2"><a href="">LEARN MORE</a></div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

**CSS**

```
.text1 {
  margin-top: 30px;
  position:absolute;
  text-align: left;
  color: #bc7e09;
}
.yellow_box{
  margin-left: 60px;
  position: absolute;
  border: 5px solid #fde428;
  width: 40%;
  height: 300px;
}
```

If you want add back ground image for whole space , you can integrate with HTML .I hope it will help you .

Demo : https://jsfiddle.net/Ltxktaad/21/

Comment: This is very close to want I wanted. If possible can you please tell me how do I omit the line under the words "Consumer Products Consulting"? Just that portion which is under these words.

Comment: change the .main-text-wrapper height to around 130px

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide additional wrapper divs around the the text which needs to be absolutely positioned. Here is the [working example](https://codepen.io/Kartm/pen/paZLqO).

```
<div class="text_box_holder">
    <div class="yellow_box"></div>
    <div class="main-text-wrapper">
      <h1>Consumer<br>Products<br>Consulting</h1></div><div class="link-text-wrapper">
      <a href="" class="learn_more_in_box">LEARN MORE</a> </div>
  </div>

.text_box_holder{
  position: relative;

}
.text_box_holder h1{
  text-align: right;
  padding-right: 50%;
  color: green;
  background: inherit;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  text-align: left;
  position: absolute;
  top: -22px;
  margin-top: 18px;
  margin-bottom: 18px;
}
.learn_more_in_box{

  color: #fde428;
  text-align: right;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  text-align: left;
  position: absolute;
  top: 4px;
}
.yellow_box{
  position: absolute;
  border: 7px solid #fde428;
  width: 40%;
  height: 300px;
  margin-left: 45px;
  z-index:2;
}
.main-text-wrapper {
  background-color: white;
  width: 40%;
  height: 110px;
  position:absolute;
  top: 65px;
  z-index: 9999;
}
.link-text-wrapper {
  position:absolute;
  background-color: #fff;
  top: 195px;
  width:40%;
  height: 30px;
  z-index: 9999;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your effort. I am actually trying to set the background of the texts to whatever the "text_box_holder" div is in. I tried putting background-color: inherit; but the yellow line still shows up.